# Multiple Choice Knapsack

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

So the standard multiple choice knapsack problem allows 1 item to be chosen from each class to create an optimal knapsack. However, how would I go about modifying this algorithm to allow 0 or 1 items to be chosen? i.e. an item doesn't need to be chosen from each class for the optimal solution, but at most 1 item can be chosen from a class. Is it just the same algorithm allowing no item to be chosen from a class?

thanks

Comment: The 0-1 knapsack problem allows for 0 items to be selected. If the only allowable number of items is 1, the problem is trivial. What 'standard multiple choice knapsack problem' are you talking about?

Comment: wouldn't that be the same as the standard 0/1 knapsack problem?

Comment: it differs from the regular knapsack because at most 1 item can be chosen from each 'class'. See multiple choice knapsack here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems

Comment: so in that wiki example, exactly 1 item is chosen from each class. I want an algorithm that will choose 0 or 1 item from each class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just modify your original problem set by adding one zero-profit/zero-weight choice to each class.